# Work thread makes inactive dialog of the main thread MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have MFC dialog based app that has one dialog. On button click i start another work thread. Unfortunately, while function of work thread is running a can not access to controls on my dialog.

```
void CrMainDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
   //...
   CWinThread* fonThread = AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc, iP, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL);
   //...
 } 

UINT CrMainDlg::WorkerThreadProc(LPVOID Param)
{
//...
       while(/*some bool*/)
       {
           //makesomething
           Sleep(1000);
       }
       //...
}
```

Only if i write Sleep(1000) i could have access to ScrollBar or another button or something else on the main dialog. If i do not - i could access to controls only after while ends...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are making something.

Comment: What is it that you are making, and how are you doing it?

Comment: Did you set your compiler options to use the multi-threaded version of the library?

Comment: In work thread i go through vector and load some pictures on the main dialog. This vector is static and global.

Comment: Zac, how to set such option in VS2010 ?

Comment: In your Project Settings under C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library.  What is the option set to?

Comment: Zac, ty it is multithreading debug there.

Comment: I got it in fact. It happens because i PostMessage in this while to the main thread. PostMessage with Invalidate() func in it.

Comment: Why the `PostMessage`? When you call `Invalidate()` the system will eventually generate a `WM_PAINT` message, once the message queue is empty. If you continuously call `PostMessage` the message queue may never get empty and no `WM_PAINT` ever gets generated.

Comment: I do PostMessage witch refer on my own func. This func makes InvalidateRect() and nothing else. So i draw one picture.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The worker thread function must be static. If it is not declared static the code you have posted will not compile. (2) The worker thread should not access any controls, only data.